# Qual é a finalidade de uma interface vazia?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Estava analisando as exceptions da engine de validação de regras [Respect Validation](http://respect.github.io/Validation/), e descobri algo que me chamou muito a atenção.

Se trata da interface `ExceptionInterface`, que aparentemente, não há nenhum código nela, ou seja, não existe membro algum para serem implementados nas classes que implementam esta interface.

Veja a [interface](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Exceptions/ExceptionInterface.php):

```
<?php   

namespace Respect\Validation\Exceptions;

interface ExceptionInterface
{
}
```

E a classe `ValidationException` implementa esta interface. E a maioria das exceptions desta engine estende da [classe](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Exceptions/ValidationException.php) `ValidationException`, tal como a [classe](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Exceptions/CpfException.php) `CpfException` que é a exception para CPFs inválidos.

## Dúvidas

1. Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade de uma interface "vazia"?
2. Uma interface "vazia" é exclusiva do PHP ou outras linguagens
   possuem interfaces "vazias" também?